# PL/SQL negation of "member of" collection does not negate

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've got a PL/SQL collection that contains an empty element (in the minimal working example it's only that, but the behavior is the same with additional elements). When I now query whether this collection has a specific number as element, it returns `false` as expected. But the strange thing is that negating the query also yields an answer of `false`.

Can anyone confirm this behavior or direct me towards my failed assumptions here?

```
DECLARE
  TYPE number_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  nt1 number_t := number_t();
BEGIN
  nt1.extend();
  dbms_output.put_line('Start');        -- prints 'Start'
  IF 1 member of nt1 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Member');     -- does not execute
  END IF;
  IF not 1 member of nt1 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Not member'); -- does not execute
  END IF;
  IF not (1 member of nt1) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Not member'); -- does not execute
  END IF;
END;
```

Observed on: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Not yet tested on other installations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Oracle documentation, "`EXTEND` appends one null element to a collection" and "the return value [of the `MEMBER` operator] is `TRUE` if `expr` is equal to a member of the specified nested table"

Comparing anything with null has an `UNKNOWN` result, so the condition is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, therefore the `THEN` block is never executed.

References:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems006.htm
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions006.htm

Comment: Is there any way I can check what this `UNKNOWN` result looks like? For example by assigning the result of `MEMBER` to a variable without actually assigning/converting it to a boolean value like with `CASE`?

Comment: Not sure what you meen by the "look" of `UNKNOWN`. It is of the `BOOLEAN` ilk, but is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, so if you assign it to a boolean variable, its value will become `UNKNOWN` as well.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that a `BOOLEAN` of `UNKNOWN` value actually `IS NULL`. So the correct way to check for `not MEMBER` would be to also check for `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, the final way I checked for `not MEMBER` taking into account possible `NULL` values was:

```
IF not 1 member of nt1 OR (1 member of nt1) IS NULL THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('NULL'); -- prints 'NULL'
END IF;
```